# Handling Database Exceptions gracefully

Tags: database, exception, design-patterns

I have a executor service, where the thread runs 2-3 multiple process on the context object , and logs the state into the database, after each process is completed.
Current code defines try and catch block after each logging statement , so that any database exceptions can be handled , and the worker moves to next process.

Is there a design pattern, or a more graceful way of doing this. The code has multiple try and catch blocks inside a single function which is not readable

Code snippet for example:

```
completePayment() {

validateAttribute1 ();
try {
logResultToDatabase() ;
//calls the entity manager to persist
}
catch (Exception e ) {
//do Nothing , continue to validateAttribute2
}
validateAttribute2 ();
try {
logResultToDatabase() ;//calls the entity manager to persist
}
catch (Exception e ) {
//do Nothing , continue to doPayment
}
doPayment();
try {
logResultToDatabase();
}
catch (Exception e ) {
//do Nothing.
}
}
```

Comment: Don't describe the code. Post it.

Comment: @jb-nizet - Added  a sample code snippet to explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never catch Exception. You should only catch the exception that you intend to handle, and not some unrelated exception (like a NullPointerException caused by a bug in the code, for example).

You said that you want to handle database exceptions, so the exception you should catch is SQLException.

When can a SQLException be thrown?

- when there is a bug in your code, like an invalid query for example
- or when it's not possible to communicate with the database

In the first case, catching the exception is not what you want, especially if you ignore the exception: you'd better let the exception propagate to the calling code, so that the bug doesn't go unnoticed, and can be fixed ASAP.

In the second case, either you don't care if the log wan't be written to the database, or you want to stop the multi-tep process immediately when a log fails.

If you want to stop immediately, then once again, you should let the exception propagate.

If you don't care if the logs are not written, and still want to proceed, then what you have is fine, except it contains a lot of repetitions and is not very readable.

So extract the code to a method:

```
public void completePayment() {
    validateAttribute1();
    logResult();

    validateAttribute2();
    logResult();

    doPayment();
    logResult();
}

private void logResult() {
    try {
        insertResultIntoDatabase();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // not thrown to avoid interrupting the payment process
        // but logged to be aware of the problems with the code or the DB
        logger.warn("Exception writing result to the database, e);
    }
}
```